# How to install Windows service from command line while setting recovery options

Tags: installation, service, command, options

I have a Windows service that I build on a build server and then install on multiple remote servers using Sysinternals PSExec and sc create. This was worked well to this point but I now have a need to set the recovery options for the service so the service will restart itself or the machine in the event of a failure.

In a perfect World I would be able to pass some parameters in my sc create command but it doesn't appear that easy.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in that `sc` won't manipulate these settings. These settings are stored in the  "FailureActions" REG_BINARY value, which is mostly opaque in nature. Your best bet would be to set the value as you want it on a test service then export the registry value. You would just import it after you use `sc` to create the service in your deployment script.

The API to manipulate these settings is [ChangeServiceConfig2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681988(v=vs.85).aspx), and it's conceivable that you could code something to manipulate the values as you desire if you need flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for you response Evan. I'm currently using a batch script that installs the service each time I build. It deletes the existing service using sc delete and then uses sc create to reinstall the service.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was cut off. I think I can swing the solution you presented above but it adds a couple degrees of complication. Is it possible to update the binary for my service without deleting it? If I don't delete then the recovery options would remain intact.

Comment: As long as the service is stopped you can update the binary. There's no need to re-register the service as long as the binary's path and filename remains the same.